# MySQL Workbench host mismatch

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I already installed MySql Workbench 6.3 in my laptop with an operating system of windows 10, but when I created a connection and open it there is an error which is

> Could not acquire management access for administration ''RuntimeError: Target host is configured as windows, but seems to be a different OS. Please review the connection settings.

Whenever I click the Server Status under the MANAGEMENT tab that error is pop up and after that there is a next error which is

> Unhandled exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled.

Comment: I've had the same problem and sorted it out by installing the server XAMPP. You have to start the server Apache and MySQL on it, so you can connect to the localhost. =)

Answer (score 9):

Change the configuration, edit the mySQL connections: configuration-> system type. I use linux(THERE ARE OTHER O.S).
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I got this message using MySql 8.0.27 (both server and Workbench) on Windows machine and solved this way:

- Control Panel >
- Region >
- Administrative Tab >
- Change regional system configuration
- Checked "Beta version: Use UTF-8 Unicode for world compatibility.."
- Restart

Credits: third option explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fD9JG_lfnzs

Comment: That's the only one that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue but it was not related to any configuration, the MySQL service was not running at all.

For anyone which this problem go to services and search for MySQL and start the MySQL service manually and configured for start on boot so you won't have to repeat these steps later.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved this same problem by installing MySQL Server and MySQL Workbench 8.0.22

Answer (score 3):

You have to go to the control panel, then region, then clic in the administrative tab and click on "change system regional settings" and as a final step check the box: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support, restart your PC and try to access MySQL Workbench.

[image: Check this box]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the search bar on your Windows and search for Services. Launch Services and look for MySQLxx (xx depends on your MySQL version) in the long list of services. Right-click on MySQLxx and hit Start. MySQL should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Open MySQL Workbench
click on “Manage Server Instances” under “Server Administration” column
close the screen again.
Now click on the instance again, the issue should be fixed.
Another post makes this recommendation:

Open MySQL Workbench
Click Manage Server Instances
Select System Profile tab
Check box(es) to acquire Admin privileges
Try one or both of these and see if it helps.

Comment: Hello Jonas thank you for answering. But I can't find the Server Administration? I'm using mysql workbench 6.3

Comment: This literally does nothing. It opens the "Manage Server Connections" window. And now what ?